# Nodejs - adding multiple parames to a route with regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm attempting to create my first route which takes multiple params that are filtered using regexs:

```
router.get('/circle/:radius([0-9]{1,3})/Xposition/:x(\-?[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,9})?)/Yposition/:y(\-?[0-9]{1,3})', function(req, res, next) {
console.log('x ' + req.params.x);
console.log('y ' + req.params.y);
});
```

after doing a get on something like this:
http://localhost:8080/circle/100/x/100.0/y/100.00

I get endup with the following printed:

```
 x 100.0
 y .0
```

It seems like it doesn't like my regex but I've tried using a regex tester and it seems fine. Is there something I'm missing with how it works with nodejs and express? I want to be able to take points like -100.00 and -100, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Any ideas? Also what would be a simple way to split these regexes out of the route since they are essentailly duplicated. Thanks.

Edit:
I was able to solve this by adding rh below regex and tesitng with if statement. But would still like to know if this is possible without using a separate regex

```
var pointRegex = new RegExp("^\-?[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,9})?$");
```

Comment: this is such an extremely bad idea, the only thing I can say is: start using [express](http://expressjs.com) or [hapi](http://hapijs.com/) or the like. At the very least a router package that does normal parameter parsing so you can use routes like `/base/:thing/:otherthing` and then have access to `thing` and `otherthing` variables in your handler. If you need a regex like the one you're showing here, something went dreadfully wrong.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't quite understand, I'm using express in the example, maybe you can give a simple example on what you mean? This is my first day with javascript and node  :(

Comment: If you're using express, don't use regex in your routes, use [parameters](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param) and then use them in your routes, so that in this case you get `app.get("/circle/:radius/:x/:y", ...)` and then handle the validation in the param functions. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use this kind of regex in your routes, use [parameters](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param) and then use *those* in your routes, so that in this case you get:

```
app.get("/circle/:r/:x/:y", function(req, res) {
  var r = req.params.r,
      x = req.params.x,
      y = req.params.y,
  res.json({......});
});
```

With three parameter handlers:

```
app.param("r", function(req, res, next, r) {
  if(r does not validate) next(new Error("bad radius"));
  req.params.r = r;
});

app.param("x", function(req, res, next, x) {
  if(x does not validate) next(new Error("bad x coordinate"));
  req.params.x = x;
});

app.param("y", function(req, res, next, y) {
  if(y does not validate) next(new Error("bad y coordinate"));
  req.params.y = y;
});
```

So you handle the validation in your param handlers. Do they not match what they need to be? Call `next(err)` and let the universal error handler take care of it. If they do match, you automatically fall through to your next middleware, ending in the function that forms the actual response.

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at the [express-params](https://github.com/expressjs/express-params) package.

It makes handling/defining expressions in your routes easier, IMO.

```
app.param('uid', /^[0-9]+$/);

app.get('/user/:uid', function(req, res, next){
  var uid = req.params.uid;
  res.send('user ' + uid);
});
```

2. Your route pattern could probably be simplified.

You may have a reason for what you did, but you should be able to construct it as.

```
/circle/:radius/:x/:y
```

3. So all together

It would be something like

```
app.param('x', pointRegex);
app.param('y', pointRegex);
app.param('radius', pointRegex);

router.get('/circle/:radius/:x/:y', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log('x ' + req.params.x);
   console.log('y ' + req.params.y);
   console.log('radius ' + req.params.radius);
});
```

For more information, [look at the app.param section of the Express 4.x docs.](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param)